# Decleartion of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I have just started learning about pointers and have come across the following decleration of pointers that has confused me during my studies:

```
int n1 = 2, n2 = 3, n3 = 4, n4 = 5;

int *ptr = &n3;
int *ptr1 = &n4;

n3 = n2;

*ptr1 = *ptr * n2;
*ptr1 = *ptr * *ptr1;
```

What is the value of n4 in this case now?  I got 27 as follows :

Since `ptr points to n3, *ptr = 4, and since ptr1 points to n4, *ptr1 = 5.`

Then since `n3 = n2, n3 = 3.`

Now `*ptr1 = *ptr (3) * n2 (3) = 9.`

Finally `*ptr1 = *ptr (3) * *ptr1 (9) = 27`

As shown, I got 27, but my book says 22.  Why?

Thank you!! :)

Comment: First make us understand what you did not understand?

Comment: @Acme I asked a proper question now, please help.

Comment: Throw your book and take new one. Its `27`.

Comment: Either there's more operations you're not showing or your book is wrong. The answer is 27. In fact, there is no way to end up with 22 using only multiplications with the numbers you start with

Comment: 22 has 11 as a prime factor. None of the starting numbers are 11 or an integer multiple of 11. The answer cannot possibly be 22.

Comment: there is probably some _errata corrige_ somewhere for this book

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is giving the wrong answer, you're correct. It's not at all unknown for text books to have typos.

However for this kind of thing you would do best to actually run the code and step through in a debugger, then you can see for sure that you're correct.

It's amusing exercise to figure out whether there's any way that a simple adjustment in the question could yield 22 - so far I've failed so I reckon the typo is in the answer

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see. First you assign two pointers to `n3` and `n4.`

```
int *ptr = &n3; //points to n3 = 3
int *ptr1 = &n4; //points to n4 = 5

n3 = n2; //n3 now equals 3
```

Here you tell to `n3 = n2` which is giving `n3` the value of `n2` and now it equals `n3 = 3.`

```
*ptr1 = *ptr * n2; //equals 9
```

Here you take the pointer `*ptr1`, which points on `n3` and multiply it by `n2` which is also `3`.

now you have pointer to result `9`.

```
*ptr1 = *ptr * *ptr1; //equals 27
```

Here you multiply it again by 3 which results in 27.

You are correct